# How to download 2 documents in a same page using PHPWord in Laravel

Tags: laravel, download, document, phpword

Is it possible to download 2 documents with 2 differents buttons in a same page using PhpWord?
Presently I can download only 1 document.

My controller Here and it's working nicely. Now can I create another public function a part from defaults function (create, index, delete...

```
 public function edit(Stagiaire $stagiaire, $downloadName = null)
{
    $id = $stagiaire ->id;
    $desc1 = Stagiaire::find($id);

    $my_template = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor(public_path('templateStagiaire.docx'));

    $my_template->setValue('id', $desc1->id);
    $my_template->setValue('civilite', $desc1->civilite);
    $my_template->setValue('prenoms', $desc1->prenoms);
    $my_template->setValue('nom', $desc1->nom);
    $my_template->setValue('date_enregistrement', $desc1->date_enregistrement);
    $my_template->setValue('lieu_enregistrement', $desc1->lieu_enregistrement);


    $first_name = $stagiaire->prenoms ;
    $last_name = $stagiaire->nom ;
    $filename = "Formulaire Stagiaire de "." ".  $first_name. " ". $last_name;

    try{
        $my_template->saveAs(storage_path("$filename.docx"));
    }catch (Exception $e){
        //handle exception
    }
    $downloadName = $downloadName??$filename;

    return response()->download(storage_path("$filename.docx"));

}
```

Thank for your Help.